# Mocking fs.existsSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, cypress, stub

Since `fs` is not allowed on Cypress/web browser, I am creating mocks for the `fs` functions being called in my source (non-test/Electron) code.

For example, `fs.existsSync`. This method is called many times and will return different responses. So instead of manually mocking and hard-coding all their responses, I just created a `task` inside the mock so it can be checked dynamically.

```
window.Cypress.fs = require('fs')
window.Cypress.fs.existsSync = (file) => {
  var retVal = ''
  cy.task('existsSync', file).then((result) => { retVal = result })
  return retVal
}

it('Sample test', () => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:8080')  
})
```

And in my `plugins.js`, the task is simply implemented as:

```
on('task', {
    existsSync (file) {
      return fs.existsSync(file)
    }
})
```

But then I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught Uncaught CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

  > `cy.visit()`

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

  > `cy.task()`
```

`fs.existsSync()` is being called during 'boot-up'.. So it is called during app creation (during `cy.visit()`)

How can I use `fs.existsSync`??

Help!!!

Comment: Before proceeding any further ,`window.Cypress.fs.existsSync` (WCFES) is attempting to synchronously return a value obtained asynchronously, in a future turn of the event loop's task manager. This is not possible: `retVal` is _always_ the empty string when WCFES exits.

Comment: To echo the previous comment.  You cannot synchronously return an asynchronous retrieved value in Javascript.  It cannot be done.  Your `window.Cypress.fs.existsSync()` function returns BEFORE you ever have a value in `retVal` so the return value is always `''`.  Instead, you have to access an asynchronously retrieved value via a callback or a promise.